# Using album image as thumbnail for open graph story

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I am working on a sample application in PHP to upload a picture to facebook and use that link to create a story. All is well except for the thumbnail is not showing up. Does anyone know if it is restricted to actually use the uploaded album image as a thumbnail?Below is the code i am using

```
    $ret_obj = $facebook->api('/me/photos', 'POST', array(
                                     'image' => '@'.realpath($photo),
                                     'message' => $message,));
    $imgId = $ret_obj['id'];
    $objectjson = json_encode(array('title'=>'Sample','url'=>'http://facebook.com/photo.php?fbid='.$imgId,'description'=>'This is a sample','image'=>'http://facebook.com/photo.php?fbid='.$imgId));
    $ret_obj = $facebook->api('/me/objects/xxxx:yyyy', 'POST', array(
                                     'object' => $objectjson));
```

EDIT: Forgot to mention that i am using the suggested size image and any other images other than the uploaded ones can be used as thumbnail